# Define $f(x)=\begin{cases}x^2 & \text{if } x \text{ is rational} \\-x^2 & \text{if } x \text{ is irrational}\end{cases}$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

At what points is the function continuous?

I think the function is only continuous at $x=0$ because that is the only place where the function isn't oscillating back and forth between rational numbers and irrationals, but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: @AlexR It is continuous at $x = 0$ and only there. $|f(x) - 0| \le |x - 0|$ in a neighborhood of $0$.

Comment: Yes, you can show it using $\epsilon-\delta$ argument.

Comment: It is even differentiable at $x=0$.

Comment: @All thanks, don't know what got me there.

Answer (score 2):

yes, it is continuous only at $0$.

If $x_0\neq 0$, you can prove the limit of $f(x)$ will not exist using Cauchy sequence. That is, without loss of generality, assume $x_0>0$. in the open interval $U_n:=(x_0+\frac{1}{n+1}, x_0+\frac{1}{n})$, you choose $x_n\in U_n\cap \mathbb{Q}$ and $y_n\in U_n\cap \mathbb{Q}^c$, then $|x_n-y_n|\leq \frac{2}{n}$ and $|f(x_n)-f(y_n)|=x^2_n+y_n^2\geq 2x_0^2$.

Comment: It doesn't seem like it is necessary to use the definition of Cauchy sequence, only the definition of "limit", although what you wrote does have the nice feature that you don't have to split into cases depending on whether or not $x_0$ is in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: yes, you are right, Trevor. It does not use the Cauchy sequence. Yes, $x_0\neq 0$ is any element in $\mathbb{R}$. And in my proof, it does not necessary to split into cases whether or not $x_0\in \mathbb{Q}$.