# if $f(x) = x$ if $x$ is rational $f(x) = x^2$ if $x$ is irrational Then f is continuous at 0 and 1.

Tags: metric-spaces

Let $f$ be a function on the closed interval $[0, 1]$ defined by
$f(x) = x$ if $x$ is rational
$f(x) = x^2$ if $x$ is irrational
Then $f$ is continuous at 0 and 1.

Comment: well sketch both graphs and notice the points of intersection first of all, when checking for continuity and proving this via the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ method. you will need to take care of cases that arise of points near 0 and 1 that are irrational and rational as they are dense within any interval.

Comment: Try using $$\delta \leq \epsilon$$ for x = 0 and $$\delta\leq\sqrt{\epsilon}$$ for x = 1.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Define $f(x)=\begin{cases}x^2 & \text{if } x \text{ is rational} \\-x^2 & \text{if } x \text{ is irrational}\end{cases}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/524828/define-fx-begincasesx2-textif-x-text-is-rational-x2-text)

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $f$ is continuous at $c\in\mathbb{R}$, then  by sequential criterion for continuity: any sequence $x_n\to c\Rightarrow f(x_n)\to f(c)$

suppose $x_n$  be a rational sequence and $x_n\to c$, then $f(x_n)=x_n\forall n$

and suppose $y_n$ be a irrational sequence and $y_n\to c$ then $f(y_n)=y_n^2\forall n$

if $f$ is continuous at $c$ then we have $\lim f(y_n)= \lim y_n^2=c^2\lim f(x_n)=\lim x_n=c$ so $c=c^2$ so $c=0,1$

Answer (score 0):

*Hint* : $f(x)=cont.\iff f_1(x)\to f_2(x)\iff f_1(x)-f_2(x)\to0\iff x^2-x\to0\iff x(x-1)\to0\iff\begin{cases}x\to0\\x\to1\end{cases}$

Comment: Statements like $f_1(x)\to f_2(x)$ make no sense.